# Python - Move elements in nested list

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, nested

```
def main():
    list1 =[1,2,3,4,5]
    list2 =[0,0,0,0,0]
    list3 =[6,7,8,9,10]

    list=[list1,list2,list3]

    for i in list:
      print(i)

main()
```

I have this nested list.
I want the program to ask the user which number he/she wants to move,
and to where.

I want to make a definition of each number.
Each number can only move to some valid positions.
Like 6, which have the coordinates (2,0), I want it to have two possible
options of moving. If the user says he wants to move it to (1,0) or (0,0), I want
the program to print out a new nested list with its new position.
If the user says (0,4) I want the program to print "Not a valid option. Please try again.".. and then try again..

Example:
If the user choose number 6 and want to move it to (1,0), I want the program
to print this:

```
def main():
    list1 =[1,2,3,4,5]
    list2 =[6,0,0,0,0]
    list3 =[0,7,8,9,10]

    list=[list1,list2,list3]

    for i in list:
      print(i)

main()
```

How do I do this?

Edit:

I don't know how to make different numbers move to different positions. The number 7 can only move one coordinate vertical at a time. The number 6 can only move one or two coordinates vertical at a time.

Comment: Why is `(0,4)` not a valid option?

Comment: He wants the lists ordered it seems. Hence the *not valid* option.

Comment: Sudipta Chatterjee:
It was just an example. But as I said, each number can only move to some valid positions. I want 6 to be able to move to (1,0) and (0,0) and nothing else.

Comment: Please, NEVER assign variables to builtin names such as `list`! If you really need to name it something like that, name it `list_`, please.

Answer (score 0):

So you want the user to choose an element from the matrix by coordinates, first the user picks a coordinate and then another coordinate that is only valid if it is adjacent to the first. This worked for me, although you should check that your coordinate system is clear to the user beforehand (perhaps you can look at pprint or some other tool to print a list of lists like a matrix).

```
def main():
    list1 =[1,2,3,4,5]
    list2 =[0,0,0,0,0]
    list3 =[6,7,8,9,10]
    list2d = [list1, list2, list3]

    print(list2d)
    trade(list2d)

def trade(list2d):
    pos1 = raw_input('Enter the coordinates of the number you want to move.')
    pos1 = map(int,pos1)
    pos2 = raw_input('Enter the coordinates of the new position.')
    pos2 = map(int,pos2)
    if (abs(pos1[0]-pos2[0]) == 1 and abs(pos1[1]-pos2[2]) == 0) or (abs(pos1[0]-pos2[0]) == 0 and abs(pos1[1]-pos2[1]) == 1):
        firstval = list2d[pos1[0]][pos1[1]]
        secondval = list2d[pos2[0]][pos2[1]]
        list2d[pos1[0]][pos1[1]] = secondval
        list2d[pos2[0]][pos2[1]] = firstval
        print(list2d)
        trade(list2d)
    else:
        print("Not a valid option. Please try again.")
        trade(list2d)


main()
```